# How to convert a string into an identifier in python?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of similar functions:

```
def func1(a)
    foo(a=a)

def func2(b)
    foo(b=b)
...
```

the only difference of them is the argument name of foo, is that a short way to define them as one function, such as passing a argument name to the functions?

Comment: What's `foo`? It seems odd that you would have functions defined like this.

Comment: Why not just `foo(a)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by unpacking a [keyword argument dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
def combined(name, value):
    foo(**{name:value})
```

Then `combined('a', a)` is equivalent to `func1(a)`. Whether this is a good idea is a separate consideration.